# SSH Issue from GCloud

Tags: linux, ssh, gcloud

so I've an ubuntu server on Google Cloud which I lost access to SSH somehow, I don't get any error when I try to login, It just keeps loading, and nothing happens, I assume It's because of proftpd or Apache which I Installed minutes before It stopped working, from what I can see on the firewall the 22 port are open, http and http are too, I need some help, what should I do to get my access back? I can login Google Shell, but I can't log in on my VM even on GCloud Itself...

from PuTTY I get this:
Network error: Connection timed out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use the VM serial console to debug. My guess is that proftpd is colliding with OpenSSH breaking SSH communications. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console